# Manifold optimization theory

Tags: manifold-learning

Does there exist some elementary book for optimization on manifolds for problems in finance/economics?

Comment: I only know of [this one](https://www.amazon.com/Optimization-Algorithms-Matrix-Manifolds-Absil/dp/0691132984/ref=sr_1_1?keywords=optimization+on+manifolds&qid=1572718843&sr=8-1).  If that does not help, you shoud explain why. Look into its references.

Comment: @kjetil b halvorsen I believe it is ok for an elementary book. That is wha I want. Thank you!